# Proving a piecewise function is discontinuous

Tags: continuity, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that
$f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ by
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x = 0$} \\ 
0 & \text{if $x \in (0,1]$}. 
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous at $x = 0$. This is obvious from the graph or just by taking left- and right-handed limits, but I'm trying to prove it using $\epsilon$-$\delta$, which I believe I can do even though I can't actually consider a neighborhood of $0$ (since $f$ isn't defined for negative $x$). This is my attempt.

> Let $\epsilon = 1$. Then for any $\delta > 0$, pick any $x' \in [0,1] \cap \left(- \delta, \delta \right)$ with $x' \neq 0$. We then have
> \begin{align*}
> |f(x') - f(0)| = |0 - 1| = 1 \geq \epsilon, 
> \end{align*}
> so $f$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Take $x'={\rm min}(\delta/2,1/2)$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Can you explain a bit more about where this comes from? I'm not totally sure I understand.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but to show that $x'$ exists, one can take concrete value. I proposed value $x'$ such that $x'\neq 0$, $|x'-0|<\delta$, $x'\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Got it, thank you.